# /signalr/hubs 404 error after upgrading DLLs

Tags: signalr, http-status-code-404, startup

I know there are many questions about this but I can't find any that help. I have a large web application that has been using SignalR since day one and has been fine. This morning we updated some of our DLLs to the latest version, these being:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client v2.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core v2.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb v2.2.3
- Microsoft.Owin v4
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener v4
- Microsoft.Owin.Hosting v4
- Microsoft.Owin.Security v4
- Owin v1

Since then I keep getting a 404 for the hubs folder. Below is my Startup.cs which hasn't changed in months.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Proj.Web.SignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had removed a dependency DLL during the migration process.

`Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` is definitely needed!